# Pythonanywhere TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/

Tags: django, django-templates, pythonanywhere

When I run my app locally it works, but when I tried uploading it to pythonanywhere I get the following error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/

How do I fix this? If it will help my files are positioned like this:

```
Music (the Django project folder)
  |_manage.py
  |_Music (the folder that contains settings file)
  |_App (the App itself with models, views etc. and my templates is here too)
    |_templates
      |_App
      |_registration
        |_login.html
```

If you need more information I can upload it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to config `TEMPLATES` variable in `settings.py`.

When you run `manage.py runserver`, the dev server has auto-discovering capabilities that a production server does not. So you need to tell him where to find you templates.